# Sort items in one collection by a value in another collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 IEnumerable collections of objects in memory.

Collection1 is a list containing:

```
Id, Name, Category etc.
```

Collection2 is a list containing

```
Id, SortOrder
```

*Id* in each collection will have corresponding values.

*SortOrder* is an int.

I need to sort *Collection1* by the value of *SortOrder* from *Collection2*

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Join them, and order by `SortOrder` - same as you would in a sql query.

Comment: What is the value in SortOrder? Is it the actual sort order (like ASC/DESC), the Name of the Column to be sorted by or the actual sequence you want them to appear? There are a few ways to do this depending on the data you are storing in that column.

Comment: NOt necessary to join

Comment: @alerya not strictly *necessary* but if you're not going to join then at least do it efficiently!

Comment: @SteveP - the value of sort order is an int

Comment: @alerya if you don't join what would you do?

Comment: As others have stated, just join the tables together and sort on that column then.

Comment: @wingyip you know you have 2 answers.

Comment: @alerya - oic you answered below - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably simply want to join them and order by the right field

```
   from obj1 in collection1
   join obj2 in collection2 on obj1.Id equals obj2.Id
   orderby obj2.SortOrder
   select obj1
```

Or, If like me you prefer Lamda syntax

```
var result = collection1.Join(collection2, 
                              a => a.Id, 
                              b => b.Id,
                             (a, b) => new {Obj1 = a,Obj2 = b})
                        .OrderBy(x => x.Obj2.SortOrder)
                        .Select(x => x.Obj1);
```

The way to do this *without* joining is to make the Id/Sortorder collection into a dictionary and lookup the sortorder:

```
var sortOrderDict = collection2.ToDictionary(k => k.Id, v => v.SortOrder);
var result = coll1.OrderBy(x => sortOrderDict[x.Id]);
```

Comment: I think it is worth noting that `Enumerable.Join` essentially does the same as the `ToDictionary` internally, using a `Lookup`, and is as efficient as possible.

Comment: In fact I can make the Id, SortOrder items a dictionary<int,int> - they are not from a database.  So it looks like the second option you suggest is going to be the most efficient.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var coll1 = new List<(int Id, string Name, string Category)>
        {
            (1,"A","AA"),
            (2,"B","BB"),
            (3,"C","CC"),
            (4,"D","DD"),
            (5,"E","EE")
        };



        var coll2 = new List<(int Id, int Order)>
        {
            (5,1),
            (4,2),
            (3,3),
            (2,4),
            (1,5),
            (0,6)
        };

        var sorted = coll1.OrderBy(x => coll2.FirstOrDefault(y => x.Id == y.Id).Order);

        foreach (var item in sorted)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```

Result

```
(5, E, EE)
(4, D, DD)
(3, C, CC)
(2, B, BB)
(1, A, AA)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

And this elegant way you can even shuffle:

```
var sorted = coll1.OrderBy(_ => Guid.NewGuid());
```

Comment: This `var sorted = coll1.OrderBy(x => coll2.FirstOrDefault(y => x.Id == y.Id).Order);` is *massively* inefficient. Small lists, fine. Bigger lists terrible!

Comment: NRE in struct  LOL, - congratulations! Showing shuffling is not wrong answer.

Comment: Ok I missed it would be a struct. But still inefficient.

Comment: Where is question about efficience ?

Comment: for short lists your answer is not efficient. But question wasn't about efficience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169611/discussion-between-alerya-and-jamiec).

Answer (score -2):

```
// here sortedlist1 will be sorted    
var sortedlist1 = list1.OrderBy(x=>x.id = GetOrder(x.id));

public int Getorder(int id)
{
    return list2.Where(x=> x.id ==id).FirstOrDefault().SortedOrder;
}
```

it works for me..